# Add different logo to wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have a theme i am customizing on wordpress(Increate themes), the thing is the owner wants a page that talks something different and it will also have a different logo, my question is how can i insert a different logo to the page.

this is my theme header.php logo part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php global $ht_options; ?>

<!-- favicon -->
<?php if($ht_options['custom_favicon']) { echo ht_favicon($ht_options['custom_favicon']);} ?>

<?php if($ht_options['apple_ipad_logo']): ?>
<!-- For iPad -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo $ht_options['apple_ipad_logo']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($ht_options['apple_logo']): ?>
<!-- For iPhone -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo $ht_options['apple_logo']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>    

<!-- responsive -->
<?php if( $ht_options['responsive_layout'] =='responsive' ) {?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
<?php } ?>


<!--[if IE]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=EmulateIE8; IE=EDGE" />
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- RSS feed -->
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php if ( $ht_options['rss_id'] <> "" ) { echo $ht_options['rss_id']; } else { echo get_bloginfo_rss('rss2_url'); } ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
 <?php echo $ht_options['before_head']; ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>   

</head>
<?php
$dark_layout = '';
if( $ht_options['dark_skin'] ){
$dark_layout = 'dark-layout';
} 
?>
<body <?php body_class($dark_layout); ?>>
<div id="frame_">
    <div id="layout" class="<?php echo $ht_options['layout_type']; ?> ">
        <header id="header">
        <?php if(!$ht_options['disable_top_header']) {?>
            <div class="head_up">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="l_ht">
                    <?php echo $ht_options['top_header_info'];?>
                    </div><!-- end text left -->

                    <div class="r_ht">
                    <?php 
                    if( is_woocommerce_activated() ): 
                        global $woocommerce;
                        $total_amount     = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); 
                        $cart_item_counts = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
                        $cart_url         = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
                        $checkout_url     = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
                    ?>                        
                        <div class="shopping_bag">
                            <div class="header_bag">
                                <a href="<?php echo $cart_url;?>"><i class="icon_bag_alt"></i><span> <?php echo $cart_item_counts;?> <?php _e("item(s)", "highthemes");?> / <?php echo $total_amount;?></span></a>
                            </div><!-- .header_bag -->
                            <div class="view_cart_mini">
                                <div class="view_cart">
                                <?php if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {?>
                                    <ul class="cart_list">
                                    <?php
                                        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                                            $_product = $values['data'];
                                            if ( $_product->exists() && $values['quantity'] > 0 ) {
                                                ?>
                                        <li class="clearfix">
                                            <?php
                                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $values, $cart_item_key );
                                            printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters('woocommerce_in_cart_product_id', $values['product_id'] ) ) ), $thumbnail );
                                            ?>                                                
                                            <div class="cart_list_product_title">
                                                <?php
                                                if ( ! $_product->is_visible() || ( ! empty( $_product->variation_id ) && ! $_product->parent_is_visible() ) )
                                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $values, $cart_item_key );
                                                else
                                                    printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters('woocommerce_in_cart_product_id', $values['product_id'] ) ) ), apply_filters('woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $values, $cart_item_key ) );

                                                // Meta data
                                                echo $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data( $values );

                                                // Backorder notification
                                                if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $values['quantity'] ) )
                                                    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . __( 'Available on backorder', 'highthemes' ) . '</p>';

                                                if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                                    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1', $cart_item_key );
                                                } else {
                                                    $product_quantity = esc_attr( $values['quantity'] );
                                                }
                                                ?>                                       
                                                <div class="cart_list_product_quantity"><?php _e("Quantity", "highthemes");?>: <?php echo $product_quantity;?> / <?php
                                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="remove toptip" title="%s">[x]</a>', esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __( 'Remove this item', 'highthemes' ) ), $cart_item_key );
                                                ?>
                                                </div><!-- .cart_list_prodcut_quantity -->
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </ul><!-- .cart_list-->
                                    <span class="total_checkout fll"><?php _e("Cart subtotal", "highthemes");?></span>
                                    <span class="amount_total flr">
                                    <?php
                                    echo $total_amount;

                                    ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="tac" style="clear:both">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $cart_url;?>" class="tbutton mt small"><span><?php _e("View Cart", "highthemes");?></span></a>   
                                        <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url;?>" class="tbutton mt small"><span><i class="icon_cart_alt mi"></i><?php _e("Checkout", "highthemes");?></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } else { // end check if cart    ?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php _e("Your cart is empty!", "highthemes");?>
                                    </p>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif // if woocommerc is activated;?>
                    <?php 
                    if( function_exists('icl_get_languages') ){
                        $langs = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=1');
                        if($langs) {
                            $current_lang = '';
                            foreach ($langs as $key => $lang) {
                                if($lang['active']){
                                    $current_lang = $lang;
                                    unset($langs[$key]);
                                }
                            }
                    ?>
                        <div class="languages">
                        <?php if ( $current_lang ) {
                           echo '<a title="'.$lang['native_name'].'" href="'. $current_lang['url'] .'"><span>'. strtoupper($current_lang['language_code']) .'</span></a>';
                        }?>

                            <div class="other_languages">
                            <?php
                                foreach ($langs as $key => $lang) {
                                    echo '<a title="'.$lang['native_name'].'" href="'. $lang['url'] .'"><span>'. strtoupper($lang['language_code']) .'</span></a>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            </div><!-- end other -->
                        </div><!-- end languages -->
                    <?php } }// end wpml ?>
                        <div class="social social_head">
                           <?php echo ht_social_icons_list();?>
                        </div><!-- end social -->

                    </div><!-- end social and bag -->
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div><!-- head -->
        <?php }?>
        <?php 
        $sticky_header = '';
        if( $ht_options['sticky_header'] ) {
            $sticky_header = 'my_sticky';
        }
        ?>
            <div class="headdown <?php echo $sticky_header;?>">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a title="<?php bloginfo("description");?>" href="<?php echo home_url();?>">
                            <?php if ($ht_options['logo_url']) { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $ht_options['logo_url'];?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"/>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>

                         <?php }?>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(!$ht_options['disable_top_search']) {?>
                    <div class="search">
                        <div class="search_icon"><i class="icon_search icon_close"></i></div>
                        <div class="s_form">
                            <form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/" id="search" method="get">
                                <input id="inputhead" name="s" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value=='<?php _e("Start Searching...", "highthemes");?>') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = '<?php _e("Start Searching...", "highthemes");?>';" value="<?php _e("Start Searching...", "highthemes");?>" placeholder="<?php _e("Start Searching...", "highthemes");?>">
                                <button type="submit"><i class="icon_search"></i></button>
                            </form><!-- end form -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu_class' => 'sf-menu', 'menu_id' => 'menu',  'menu' => 'default',  'container' => 'nav','theme_location' => 'nav', 'container_id' => 'nav' ) );  ?>
            <!-- end nav -->
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div><!-- headdown -->
        </header><!-- end header -->


    <?php 
    $ht_header_type = '';
    if($post){
        $ht_header_type = ht_get_header_type(get_the_ID());       
    }
    ?> 
    <?php if ( is_page_template('tpl-under-construction.php') ) {?>
    <?php } elseif( $ht_header_type =='rev-slider' ) { ?>
    <div class="sliderr" id="main-slideshow">
    <?php
    if(function_exists('putRevSlider')) {
       putRevSlider(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_ht_rev_slider', true));
    }
    ?>
    </div>  
    <?php 
    $overlay_caption_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_caption_title', true );
    $overlay_button1_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button1_title', true );
    $overlay_button1_link  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button1_link', true );
    $overlay_button1_icon  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button1_icon', true );
    $overlay_button2_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button2_title', true );
    $overlay_button2_link  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button2_link', true );
    $overlay_button2_icon  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_overlay_button2_icon', true );

    if( !empty($overlay_button1_title) || !empty($overlay_button2_title) || !empty($overlay_caption_title) )  {?>
    <div class="intro_p tac">
        <div class="row inner clearfix">
        <?php if( !empty($overlay_caption_title) ) {?>
            <h2><?php echo $overlay_caption_title;?></h2>
        <?php }?>
        <?php if( !empty($overlay_button1_title) ) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $overlay_button1_link;?>" class="tbutton large">
            <?php if( !empty($overlay_button1_icon) ) {?><i class="<?php echo $overlay_button1_icon;?>"></i><?php }?>
            <span><?php echo $overlay_button1_title;?></span></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if( !empty($overlay_button2_title) ) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $overlay_button2_link;?>" class="tbutton large m_left">
            <?php if( !empty($overlay_button2_icon) ) {?><i class="<?php echo $overlay_button2_icon;?>"></i><?php }?>
            <span><?php echo $overlay_button2_title;?></span></a>
        <?php } ?>            
        </div><!-- End row -->
    </div><!-- End intro p -->     
    <?php }?>        
    <?php } else if ( $ht_header_type =='title' ) {
        $header_bg_repeat = $header_bg_position = $header_bg_cover = '';

        if(is_page() || is_single() ) {
            $header_centered    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_centered', true );
        }
        $header_background  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_background', true );

        if( empty($header_background) || $header_background =='default'  ) {
            $header_bg    =  'background-image:url('.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/assets/breadcrumb1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size:cover; background-size: cover;' ;

        } elseif ( $header_background == 'custom' ) {

            $header_bg          = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_bg', true );
            $header_bg_repeat   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_bg_repeat', true );
            $header_bg_position = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_bg_position', true );
            $header_bg_cover    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_header_bg_cover', true );
            $header_bg          = ( !empty($header_bg) ) ?  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $header_bg, 'full')  : '';
            $header_bg          = ( !empty($header_bg) ) ?  'background-image:url(' . $header_bg[0] . ');' : '';
            $header_bg_repeat   = ( !empty($header_bg) ) ?  'background-repeat:' . $header_bg_repeat . ';' : '';
            $header_bg_position = ( !empty($header_bg) ) ?  'background-position:' . $header_bg_position . ';' : '';
            $header_bg_cover    = ( !empty($header_bg) && !empty($header_bg_cover) ) ?  'background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size:cover; background-size: cover;' : '';                

        } else {
            $header_bg    =  'background-image:url('.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/assets/'.$header_background.'); background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size:cover; background-size: cover;' ;

        }

        $header_centered    = ( !empty($header_centered) ) ?  ' centered' : '';


        $styles = 
                  $header_bg.
                  $header_bg_repeat.
                  $header_bg_position.
                  $header_bg_cover;

    ?>

        <div class="breadcrumb-place" style="<?php echo $styles;?>">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <h3 class="page-title">
                <?php
                if( is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
                    if( is_shop() ) {
                             woocommerce_page_title(); 
                    }

                }
                if ( is_page() || is_single() ) the_title();
                else if ( is_category() ) _e("Category : ",'highthemes'). single_cat_title('', true);
                else if ( is_tag() ) _e("Tag : ",'highthemes').single_tag_title('', true);
                else if ( is_year() ) echo get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'highthemes' ) );
                else if ( is_month() )  echo get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'highthemes' ) );
                else if ( is_day() )  echo get_the_date();
                else if ( is_author() ) echo get_the_author();
                else if ( is_search() ) printf( __('Search results for','highthemes') . " %s", '"' . get_search_query() . '"' );
                else if ( is_tax() ) {
                    global $wp_query;
                    $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                    echo $term->name;
                } 
                ?>
                </h3>
                <?php
                if( !is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
                   if($ht_options['breadcrumb_inner']){ ?>
                            <?php if (class_exists('simple_breadcrumb')) { $bc = new simple_breadcrumb; } ?>
                <?php }
                } else {
                    if(( is_woocommerce() || is_cart()  ||  is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) and ($ht_options['breadcrumb_inner'])) {
                            woocommerce_breadcrumb();
                    } else if ($ht_options['breadcrumb_inner']) {
                        ?>
                        <div id="breadcrumb" class="<?php echo $header_centered;?>">
                            <?php if (class_exists('simple_breadcrumb')) { $bc = new simple_breadcrumb; } ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                }
                ?>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- end breadcrumb place -->
    <?php } else if ( $ht_header_type =='no-title' ) {  } ?>   
        <?php if(is_404()){?>

        <div class="error_page">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="CLE">
                    <i class="icon_dislike errori"></i>
                    <h2 class="tac mtt"> <?php _e("PAGE NOT FOUND", "highthemes");?> <small> <?php _e("The page you are looking for might have been removed.","highthemes");?> </small></h2>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>" class="tbutton medium"><span><i class="icons-arrow-left mi"></i> <?php _e("Back To Homepage", "highthemes");?></span></a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- end 404 place -->
        <?php }?>

        <?php 
        if( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'portfolio' ) { 
            $portfolio_single_layout = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_portfolio_single_layout', true);
            if($portfolio_single_layout == 'image_left' || $portfolio_single_layout == 'image_right'){
        ?> 
            <div  class="hidden-x page-content no-sidebar">
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div  class="hidden-x page-content <?php echo ht_sidebar_layout();?>">
            <?php }?>

        <?php } else {?>
        <div  class="hidden-x page-content <?php echo ht_sidebar_layout();?> ">
        <?php }?>
```

Comment: Please is anyone there? can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something on header.php

```
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] != '/the-page-you-want-a-custom-logo/index.php') {
    <?php if ($ht_options['logo_url']) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $ht_options['logo_url'];?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"/>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
    <?php }?>
} else {
    <img  src="/images/yourcustomlogo.jpg" alt="Logo"/>
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ceasar Bielich, I would like to know if i should overwrite the existing logo area on the header or just add this?

Comment: just replace whats inside `<a title="<?php bloginfo("description");?>" href="<?php echo home_url();?>">` with the code

Comment: Hello @Cesar, i did what you said and it showed 2 logos in all pages. I change my quetion to my full hearder.php code, can you please modify it for me so i can change the new logo url and page id. I have added it to my previous question

Comment: @Tina Is this new logo appearing on all pages of the website or just one particular one?

Comment: the old logo appearing twice on all pages